# Facebook Comments url and moderator panel

Tags: facebook, comments

I'm using that code to comment one the add pages

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d){  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/{$locale}/all.js#appId=144809282228099&xfbml=1";  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);}(document));</script><div class="fb-comments" data-href="{$url}" data-num-posts="{$posts}" data-returnurl="{$url}" ata-callbackurl="{$url}" data-origin="{$url}" data-admins="559570439" data-xid="{$url}" data-width="{$width}" data-colorscheme="{$theme}" data-send="{$send}" data-layout="{$layout}" data-show-faces="{$faces}" data-font="{$font}"></div>
```

But on facebook wall i'm getting the link to site main page.

What is wrong with that ? Also Comments are displaying ok but nothing in moderator panel. Why?

exaple
http://www.mydisput.com/forums/index.php?/classifieds/item/84-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-intel%C2%AE-core%E2%84%A22-duo/